# How to undo `hg pull`?

Tags: mercurial

I accidentally did a `hg pull` and it created a branch in my local repo.

What is the simplest to undo that and get my local repo back to previous state?

Comment: Given that pull will not alter your working folders nor actually require you to do anything to act on its results, its worth thinking through whether there is any real need to undo a pull.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`hg rollback` but beware the caveats:

> This command should be used with care.
>   There is only  one  level of 
>   rollback,  and  there  is no way to
>   undo a rollback. It will also restore
>   the dirstate at the time of the  last 
>   transaction, losing  any  dirstate
>   changes since that time. This command
>   does not alter the working directory.
>   ...

Comment: +1. Didn't know that rollback would do that for multiple pulled changesets.

Comment: Too easy! I new `hg rollback` but thought it only worked to undo `hg commit`. RTM :)